# nodejs form submission work on postman but does not work in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to submit a form data using mongoose in nodejs to my database but when i run the code on postman it works ok and fine but not in the browser.. and no data is save to the database..  i cant figure out why.. please any help?

```
<div class="card bg-primary text-center card-form ">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3>sign up </h3>
                                <p>fill up the form below to register</p>
                                <form action="/users" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="LastName">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/register");
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName : { type: String, required: true},
    firstName : {type: String, required: true},
    lastName :  {type: String, required: true}
});

var users = mongoose.model("users", mySchema);

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{ 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/users", (req, res)=>{
    var myData = new users(req.body);
    myData.save().then(item =>{
        res.send(" your data has been saved in our database ");
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).send("sorry, we are unable to save your data")
    });
} );

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("we are listenning on port 3000")
})
```

Comment: Please post the message (headers + body) as sent by postman and as sent by your browser.

Comment: in the browser, it sends the err massage "sorry, we are unable to save your data" but in postman it works and the .then() sends the message "your data has been saved in our database"

Comment: I meant the data from the network tab of the dev pane (ctrl + shift + i)